# Power surge or missing kernel?

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard

Recently the power went on and off in my house. My closet server running a headless ubuntu 14 was affected. I pulled it out of the closet, plugged in an old monitor and now when I start up I'm having trouble with keyboard inputs.

I know the keyboard works fine, because I've entered the BIOS settings and tabbed around. But once the computer runs through boot, I'm stuck with:

```
Ubuntu 14.05.5 LTS uboxy tty1 
uboxy login:
```

"Uboxy" is the name of the computer. I've been unable to get it enter grub, by hitting shift key on boot. Then I remembered the perennial problem I've had of the `/boot` partition filling up. And how I recently cleaned it up, but might've done something different than usual. (I actually tried cleaning it out before running out of room). I definitely don't think it has been booted since that clean-up. So now I'm thinking that's the issue.

So what's the solution? Do I need to boot the machine from disk/usb, then reinstall Ubuntu into `/boot`?

Comment: Neither your root or user accounts work?

Comment: there's no action on the command line when I type anything, enter, no keys seems to create responses.